# Dynamically manage arrays to combobox'es

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make my code compact and easily expendable and now I have bumped into a problem.

I have 18 comboxes which might be more in the future, these should be initialized with an array:

Array_MyFirstDataSet ...

So if I name all my comboboxes with this naming pattern 
ComboBox_MyFirstDataSet ...

but I can not figure out how to dynamically assign 
ComboBox_MyFirstDataSet.List=Array_MyFirstDataSet

So should I add all the arrays to a dictonary instead of keeping them as independent arrays?

My non working code is below,

Create arrays:

```
Public Sub initPartslist()

If CPearson.IsArrayEmpty(Settings.Array_Type) Then
    Settings.Array_Type = Split("NA,PRT,ASM,SHEET,WELD PRT,WELD ASS,WELD MRG", ",")
End If

If CPearson.IsArrayEmpty(Settings.Array_SpeedSelect) Then
    Settings.Array_SpeedSelect = Split("NA,Fresing,Dreiing,Vannskjæring,Dreiing og Fresing,Fresing og Dreiing,Sveising,Montering", ",")

End If
```

And here I try to add the arrays to the comboboxes

```
Public Sub initComboBox() 'rowNumber As Integer
Dim cCont As control
Dim cName As String

'All members in Frame_MOM
For Each cCont In MOM.Frame_MOM.Controls
    If TypeName(cCont) = "ComboBox" Then
    cName = replace(cCont.name, "ComboBox", "Array")
    cCont.List = Settings.cName
    End If
Next cCont
```

Comment: Short answer: yes, if you want to refer to them by name.

Comment: @Skatun, please take your time to close your previous posts before posting new ones. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are nearly there. It will work if `Settings.cName` is an array. Like this:

```
Dim cName(2, 0 to 2)
cName(0, 0) = "John"
cName(0, 1) = 1982
...
cCont.List = Settings.cName
```

Comment: 'cCont.List = Settings.cName' Dont see how this work,  I did not want to type CCont1.list=array1 ......  CCont18.list = array18

Comment: @skatun: this was the answer to "how to dynamically assign...". If you want to know how to dynamically manage controls, read this: `http://yoursumbuddy.com/userform-event-class-multiple-control-types/`. It will tell you how to prepare and manage an array or collection of controls giving you a freedom to manage all of them in a unified way.